# Deploy python 3.6.5 Django app on heroku-18 stack

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, django-deployment

So, I am deploying my first django app to heroku for the first time. I have configured the app locally, pushed it to my remote repository. But when I push the code to my heroku repository, the build fails giving the reason that python 3.6.5 is not available on current stack (heroku-18). It also says [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#build-behavior) that heroku-18 supports 3.6.6. My simple question is "How do I deploy my python 3.6.5 app on current stack (heroku-18)?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a [`runtime.txt`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime) file, try changing it to python-3.6.6. 3.6.6 is a maintenance release, so code written for 3.6.5 should run on it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just try put it in your `runtime.txt`

```
python-3.6.4
```

It's working to me.